# How to activate a wakelock in android for all time?

Tags: android, android-source, wakelock, android-wake-lock

For my Android 7.1 ROM, I need a special property. I want a wakelock to be active all the time. i.e. even when there is no playing music,... I want to have a active wakelock when I run `dumpsys power`.

Can I activate such a lock in init script in android? How this can be achieved?

Thanks